# how to get datebox close event in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, ios, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

Hi I am using JqueryMobile-1.3.0 and Cordova-2.1.0 for iOS app.I am using jqm datebox for date selection.Everything is working fine but I want to capture the close event of date box because I want to do something when the datebox is closed.How to do this?

Comment: Can you provide us with more information?
What is the jam datebox and where can we find it?

Comment: sorry its a spelling mistake actuly its jam datebox.I am using jqm-datebox.core.min.js and jqm-datebox.mode.calbox.min.js.You can check this http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made you a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/ktbcP/

This is the code you need:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
  $('#mydate').on('datebox', function(e, p) {
    if ( p.method === 'close' ) {
        alert('DO SOMETHING');
    }
  });
});
```

Other callbacks and events can be found here: http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/demos/api/events.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Gajotres for quick reply.I will try this and let you know